# could ipvs virtual IP address be 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux

I want to bind a service to a node port, for example, to bind a service to port 9090, then any client access port 9090 will be redirected to the backend service. Thus I want to `ipvsadm -A -t 0.0.0.0:9991 -s rr`. Could ipvs support this?

Comment: ipvs rule is quintuple(ServiceIP, ServicePort, DestinationIP, DestinationPort), could the ServiceIP be 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)